# System.Net.WebRequest not presenting my certificate

Tags: powershell, ssl, service, web, certificate

Below is a snippet of code I have written to make a SOAP request to an internal Web Service we have.  If I run this with Fiddler running Fiddler alerts that the site is requesting a cert.  If I provide the cert to Fiddler this runs perfectly.  If I turn off Fidler then I get an error that the connection was closed.  I am beating my head against the wall because I am adding the cert to the ClientCertificates collection, and when I debug it I can see that it has it.  Any ideas why it is not presenting it at run time?  (you will see where I have tested with grabbing it from the local machine store and creating it from the file, and neither option is working)

```
            $cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::CreateFromCertFile($certPath)
            #$cert = get-item cert:\LocalMachine\* | get-ChildItem | Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.FriendlyName -eq "HRSYS")}
            $soapWebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
            $soapWebRequest.ClientCertificates.Add($cert)
            $soapWebRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://service.wellsfargo.com/provider/hr/entity/teamMemberData/getTeamMemberProfileById/2010/12/") 
            $soapWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=`"utf-8`"" 
            $soapWebRequest.Accept = "text/xml" 
            $soapWebRequest.Method = "POST" 
            $soapWebRequest.Timeout = 60000
            $soapWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
```

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer to this.  I had to grant permissions to the private key.  To test I cheated and just added it for everyone.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Resource Kits\Tools>winhttpcertcfg.exe -g -c "LOCAL_MACHINE\my" -s HRSYS -a Everyone

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `X509Certificate2.CreateFromCertFile` is designed to load only a *certificate*, not a certificate with its *private key*, which is what you need to use a client certificate.

`X509Certificate2` is a class that models an X.509 certificate, but also has the ability to associate a private key to it (the private key is not part of the certificate, although it's necessary to authenticate using the certificate).

Using the [`X509Certificate2(String, SecureString)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148419) constructor would be a better way to load your certificate, from a PKCS#12 file with its password.

Note that using Fiddler as a MITM SSL/TLS proxy will make client-certificate authentication fail anyway, even if your client sends the client-certificate successfully. This is because Fiddler will present a server-certificate that isn't the genuine cert sent by the server, thereby producing a different handshake. Since client-certificate authentication relies on the client signing a digest of the whole handshake so that the server can compare it with its own accounts of the handshake, and since the handshakes as seen by the client and the server will differ when a MITM proxy is used, client-certificate authentication will fail.

Comment: I did some testing, and it appears that you are right.  When I create the cert from file it does not appear to have a private key.  I am now getting it from the local machine store, and it definitely has the private key now, however I am still getting "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive".  I took a network trace, and the last reset is from my machine to the server, so I am now wondering if it is my machine rejecting the server's cert. I thought this line would catch it?
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}

Comment: Since you seem to be using the default trusted cert store, if IE is OK with that server cert, so should your script. Avoid `ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}` in general, since it disables trust verification. As I said, none of this will work if there's a MITM proxy (Fiddler or other). Perhaps it would be worth looking with Wireshark: if you get beyond the handshake (encrypted application data packets), then the server cert shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Right so for my testing I don't have Fiddler running.  I did a network trace, and it looks like the last reset comes from my machine to the server that is why I am wondering if it is the cert coming back.  Thanks for your help by the way.  The dialogue is very helpful.

Comment: You should write this as an answer and accept it (I think you may have to wait a day before being able to accept your own answer).